# Enumerating events occuring in time using reactive extensions (rx)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

```
 public interface Event
 {
      Guid identifier;
      Timestamp ts;
 }
```

We're thinking of using Reactive Extensions for a rewrite of a problem at my financial firm.

The premise is that we get events identified by a Guid (stock symbol + uniqueness entropy embedded into it), a timestamp, and a Value field. These come at a high rate, and we cannot act on these objects until "at least" after X seconds (10 seconds), after which we have to act on them, and remove them from the system.

Think about it like two windows, an initial window of "10 seconds" (for example T0 to T10), where we identify all the unique events (basically, group by guid), then we look into the next "10 seconds", "secondary window" (T10-T20), to make sure we're implementing the policy of "at least" 10 seconds. From the "initial window", we remove all the events (because we've accounted for them), and then from the "secondary window", we remove the ones that occurred in the "initial window". And we keep on moving 10 second sliding windows, so now we're looking at window T20-T30, repeat and rinse.

How could I implement this in Rx, because it seems like the way to go.

Comment: You say sliding windows but your example seems to use jumping windows - which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can rely on the server clock and the timestamp in the message (that is, we're in 'real life' mode), **and** you're after a sliding 10 second delay as opposed to a jumping 10 second window, then  you can just delay the events 10 seconds:

```
var events = new Subject<Event>();  
var delayedEvents = events.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Checking for unique events etc is just a matter of adding them to a set of some sort:

```
var guidSet = new HashSet<Guid>();  
delayedEvents.Do(e => guidSet.Add(e.identifier));
```

If you're problem is instead that you must wait 10 seconds and then process the last 10 seconds at once, then you just want to buffer for 10 seconds instead:

```
var bufferedEvents = events.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
bufferedEvents.Do(es => { foreach (var e in es) guidSet.Add(e.identifier); });
```

I haven't shown the example of a sliding 10 second window as I can't imagine that's what you want (events get processed more than once).

---

Now we get serious. Let's say you don't want to rely on wall time and instead want to use the time within your events to drive your logic. Assuming event is redefined as:

```
 public class Event
 {
      public Guid identifier;
      public DateTime ts;
 }
```

Create the historical scheduler and feed the scheduled events from the original ones:

```
var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler();
var driveSchedule = events.Subscribe(e => scheduler.AdvanceTo(e.ts));   
var target = events.SelectMany(e => Observable.Timer(e.ts, scheduler).Select(_ => e));
```

Now you can simply use the regular Rx combinators on `target` instead of `event`, and just pass through the scheduler so they are triggered appropriately, for example:

```
var bufferedEvents = target.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), scheduler);
```

Here's a simple test. Create a hundred events each 'virtually' 30 seconds apart but in real-time triggered every second:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var test = Enumerable.Range(0,99).Select(i =>
    Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i), 
        () => events.OnNext(new Event() { 
            identifier = Guid.NewGuid(), 
            ts = now.AddSeconds(i * 30) 
        })
    )
).ToList();
```

Subscribe to it and ask for 60 seconds of buffered events - and actually receive 2 events every 2 'real' seconds (60 virtual seconds):

```
target.Select(e => String.Format("{0} {1}", e.identifier, e.ts.ToString()))
      .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), scheduler)
      .Select(es => String.Join(" - ", es))
      .DumpLive();
```

Comment: yamen, if I read this correctly, you have a typo in MyScheduler? Or do I need to create such a scheduler?

Comment: So if I get this correctly, if I only pump 1 event in my virtual time, and say Buffer for 10 seconds in virtual time. I'll never terminate the observable, right? I hope that's true, otherwise I don't get it.

Comment: Also the reason why you receive 2 events (expected churn in 60 seconds) in 2 seconds is because of DumpLive right? If I had Subscribed to it, I would get 2 events immediately upon the 60th second in virtual time?

Comment: You're right about ```MyScheduler```, that was a typo and it's gone. The reason you get two events immediately is because it's in virtual time only. The virtual time test runs 'fast' in real-time. If you change ```TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i)``` to ```TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i * 30)``` in the test, virtual time and real-time will match and the test will run as per the real-world.

Comment: Ok and how is driveSchedule used? I don't see it being used.